# How to make div container float to side of screen regardless of screen resolution?

Tags: css, html, alignment, css-position, containers

I have a laptop and a desktop computer, the desktop being the machine I mainly work from. The monitor size for my desktop is 1920x1080 and my laptop's screen is 1366x768. I noticed one day that the project I had been working on's container div didn't show up on my laptop's screen. I need the container div to constantly stay on the right side of the screen, regardless of the resolution/size of the screen.

CSS:

```
#container {
    margin:0px auto 0 auto;
    height:800px; 
    width:960px; 
    text-align:left; 
    padding-right:0px; 
    float:right; 
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the second auto with 0 in the margin property.

```
#container {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  ...
}
```